# Yii2: How to add required attribute to a checkboxList?

Tags: model, yii2, attributes, checkboxlist, required

I have this **[checkboxList](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml#checkboxList()-detail)**:

```
Html::checkboxList('MyOffices', null, $offices);
```

It works but the user has to select at least one option. So I would like to add the required attribute to `checkboxList` but it doesn't belongs to the model.

**Update:**

I tried adding this rule to my model file but it didn't work:

```
[['MyOffices'], 'requiredValue' => 1, 'message' => 'my test message']
```

Also I tried adding the required attribute in my view file:

```
Html::checkboxList('MyOffices', null, $offices, ['required' => true]);
```

Comment: From the [docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml#checkboxList()-detail) The selected value(s). String for single or array for multiple selection(s). You have to change null with your selected value

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
['acordul_tc', 'required', 'on' => ['register'], 'requiredValue' => 1, 'message' => 'my test message']
```

This means that the attribute is required and must be equal to 1, else display error with your message.

Comment: But the checkboxList isn't defined in the model.

Comment: How about adding **MyOffices** attribute in your model? You could add the attribute and use the method rules to validate, like @RobySottini said.

Comment: @RobySottini Did you create a public attribute MyOffices in your model? You also have to use the [activeCheckboxList](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml#activeCheckboxList()-detail) to create your input based in you model. Otherwise, it won't work (you can't use the static method Html::checkboxList).

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`Html::checkboxList('MyOffices', null, $offices, ['required' => true]);`